# Why trait does not override method in class?

Tags: php, traits

I wonder if my php interpreter doesn't work correctly or if I'm understanding Traits wrong. Here's my piece of code:

```
<?php

trait ExampleTrait{
    public function foo()
    {
        echo 'y';
    }
}

class ExampleClass
{
    use ExampleTrait;

    public function foo()
    {
        echo 'x';
    }
}

$exCl = new ExampleClass();

$exCl->foo();
```

I assume this should show "y", but it shows "x" instead. Why?

Comment: From the php manual: An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

Comment: @Debflav well no, not like extended classes since when extending a class the child class will overwrite methods from the parent class(if any). While when inserting a trait inside a class, the method from the class has priority over the trait.

Comment: @AndreiP., thank you, i guess i just didn't find that in manual

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read this carefully [Trait documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)  I recommend to try out every example and make your own modifications to be sure you understand it. There is my example, hope it helps:

```
<?php
class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo "x";
    }
}

class B extends A {}

$test = new B();
$test->foo();

// result X
```

This is pretty clear I think, so now lets use a Trait:

```
<?php
class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo "x";
    }
}

trait T {
    public function foo() {
        echo "y";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    use T;
}

$test = new B();
$test->foo();

// result y
```

As you can see the Trait method overwrites the base class method. And now lets create a foo method in the B class

```
<?php
class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo "x";
    }
}

trait T {
    public function foo() {
        echo "y";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    use T;
    public function foo() {
        echo "z";
    }
}

$test = new B();
$test->foo();

// result z
```

> An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

Comment: Yes, but what if Trait has a method `bar` used in method `foo` and class A uses trait T and it overrides the trait method `bar` with it's own implementation. All good, but then B extends A and has it's own implementation of `bar`, then calling `B->foo()` will use the overwritten method `bar()` of class `A` instead of the one on `B`. That sucks :-(